# LDAP in PHP get current user details

Tags: php, ldap

I can authenticate using AD and PHP my problem is I got no idea how to get the current user displayname or cn details. This Sample code from php.com worked well for autheticating but now I need the details Anyone help?

```
// using ldap bind
$ldaprdn  = 'uname';     // ldap rdn or dn
$ldappass = 'password';  // associated password

// connect to ldap server
$ldapconn = ldap_connect("ldap.example.com")
    or die("Could not connect to LDAP server.");

if ($ldapconn) {

    // binding to ldap server
    $ldapbind = ldap_bind($ldapconn, $ldaprdn, $ldappass);

    // verify binding
    if ($ldapbind) {
        echo "LDAP bind successful...";
    } else {
        echo "LDAP bind failed...";
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Transmit a search request to the server and interpret the response. A search request (encapsulated in PHP by `ldap_search`) consists of the following at a minimum:

- a base object (or base DN in some documentation): no objects superior to the base DN ail be considered of the search result
- a search scope: `one`, `subtree`, or `base`: the depth of the search
- a filter: used to filter (narrow) the result pool
- requested attribues: this is where the LDAP client should put `cn`, `displayName`, and any other attributes needed for processing:

#### see also

- [LDAP: Mastering Search Filters](http://www.ldapguru.info/ldap/mastering-ldap-search-filters.html)
- [LDAP: Search best practices](http://www.ldapguru.info/ldap/ldap-search-best-practices.html)
- [LDAP: Programming practices](http://www.ldapguru.info/ldap/ldap-programming-practices.html)

Comment: Thanks for the answer I have attempted to use the ldap_search with the correct. I have the tree of  the group where the user belongs. I can get the results of members of the group and I know the member is there however as part of the member information there is not uid data to match the username entered with the actual name. Am I missing something?

Comment: Updated the answer. Can you insert the group entry (just the DN and `member`) and the entry to which the DN points in your original question?

Answer (score 0):

Before authenticating, store the values to be authenticate into session variables. If authentication success use the session values to display.

If authentication fails, clear the session values and try to submit the login form again.

Following is the sample code to assign the values into session variable in ZF2:

```
  $session = new Container('base');                     
  $this->session->offsetSet('username', $username);
```

and to get the session value:

```
  $sesUserName = $this->session->offsetGet('username');
```

I hope this helps.